# Install helix-p4d on arm64

Tags: 64-bit, nas, container, arm64, version-control

I'm actually trying to install a helix core server (p4d) on a QNAP TS-233 (NAS) with a Cortex-A55@2Ghz (ARM64 processor) but there is no arm64 package available from their site.

Did someone manage to do it ?

Is it possible to package p4d to an arm compatible one ?

I tried using an Ubuntu container on my qnap and Box64 to emulate x64 but only got a lot of errors in the cmake step.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: maybe your should show us the error info what you got **in the cmake step**

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install Helix Core Server on an ARM64 processor as they have discontinued support for it. I tried installing it on a Raspberry Pi and it was impossible. I also tried to find out if it could be emulated as x64, but I couldn't succeed, so in the end, I had to purchase a server with an x64 architecture. I hope this answer helps you. Best regards!